# apigee console fails with HTTP 500

Tags: apigee

I have 2 API-Proxies running. I am able to call both directly through a browser. But when I am trying to call them through Apigee Console, they are throwing HTTP500.

Here is the link I am using:
http://ritwik_chatterjee-test.apigee.net/v1/yahoo-weather/forecastrss?w=2471390

Response in Apigee Console:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-APIGEE-STATUS:
failure
X-APIGEE-ERROR:
internal-error
Content-Length:
199
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error messageid="-4868f6ff:143f9f156c9:-7995">
   <reason>An internal error has occurred. Please retry your request.</reason>
</Error>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Worked through it and found a bug.  The problem is that you have underscores in your org name (ritwik_chatterjee).  I tested with a new org named test_my_underscores and got the same problem:

```
http://test_my_underscores-test.apigee.net/v0/weather
```

Returns the same 500 error as

```
http://ritwik_chatterjee-test.apigee.net/v1/yahoo-weather/forcastrss
```

Email me at michaelb@apigee.com and I'll get you an org with dashes in it.

Answer (score 2):

Per [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), underscores are not allowed in domain names.

While org names can contain underscores, Apigee creates the default hostnames based on the org name, so if an underscore exists, this will always fail without manual manipulation of the hostname and/or organization name.

This can cause user confusion, so I will recommend we simply update the platform to allow only characters allowed in hostnames (a text string up to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus sign (-), and period (.)) upon org creation.  I will add additional notes to [YTD-3120](https://apigeesc.atlassian.net/browse/YTD-3120) mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I think i got the issue. There is seems to be bug in Apigee Console. If the host name has a underscore("_") in it the Host header and X-Target-URI go bonkers. For now, try change your URL to `ritwik-chatterjee-test.apigee.net` if possible. 
I will raise a bug and post the ticket number here

Comment: [YTD-3120](https://apigeesc.atlassian.net/browse/YTD-3120) ticket has been raised.

Answer (score 0):

There must have been an intermittent issue.  This seems to be working now.